# How to alias an output for automatic connection?

Tags: openmdao

I currently have this code:

```py
self.add_subsystem('IntegrateForTheta2Ue6', utilities.CumulativeIntegrateTrapeziums(n=n),
                               promotes_inputs=[('x', 'panel_lengths'),
                                                ('x0', 'stagnation_point_position'),
                                                ('y', 'ue5'),
                                                ('y0', 'panel_start_external_tangential_velocity')],
                               promotes_outputs=[('cumulative_integral', 'intue5')])

self.add_subsystem('ThwaitesCalculateMomentumThickness', ThwaitesCalculateMomentumThickness(n=n),
                               promotes_inputs=['external_tangential_velocities',
                                                'intue5',
                                                'kinematic_viscosity'],
                               promotes_outputs=['momentum_thickness'])
```

It does not throw any errors when run, but when debugging it is clear that the output for `intue5` aka `cumulative_integral` is not being passed into ThwaitesCalculateMomentumThickness - it appears as all ones. When I try the above with `self.connect('IntegrateForTheta2Ue6.intue5', 'ThwaitesCalculateMomentumThickness.intue5')`, I get `Attempted to connect from 'IntegrateForTheta2Ue6.intue5' to 'ThwaitesCalculateMomentumThickness.intue5', but 'IntegrateForTheta2Ue6.intue5' doesn't exist.`

Am I making a mistake in my output aliasing, or is this a bug?

Comment: I am not sure about a bug without knowing more, but to connect directly you should do: `self.connect('IntegrateForTheta2Ue6.cumulative_integral', 'ThwaitesCalculateMomentumThickness.intue5')`.

Comment: Are you calling `run_model()` before checking the outputs?  Off hand I don't see any issues that would prevent the implicit connection based on your promoted names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating to the latest version of OpenMDAO worked. I believe I was already calling run_model(), so I'm not sure why it wasn't working.